# Getting my Google Contacts contacts into Twitter to find which have Twitter accounts

Tags: twitter

Now that the "Find Friends" feature seems gone from Twitter, how can I get my Google Contacts contacts into Twitter to find which have Twitter accounts?

The nearest answer on [Twitter Help](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/upload-your-contacts-to-search-for-friends) refers to a command **Sync address book contacts** that doesn't exist on my account.

Answer (score 2):

The new design is somewhat not so easy to navigate. Here is how to find the [**`Sync address book contacts`**](https://twitter.com/settings/contacts_dashboard) settings page:
[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you can revert back to the old and familiar Twitter design :-) **[here are the instructions](https://medium.com/@ratson/how-to-switch-back-to-twitters-old-layout-design-9db3e50b151e)** how to do it...

Comment: Thanks but that just confirms Sync address book contents doesn't exist on my account. https://i.imgur.com/0F5dlXv.png . Is there anything to suggest revernting Twitter UI design would make a difference?

Comment: Indeed there are many flaws in the new Twitter design. At the end of my answer I gave you a link to "Option B". Go back to the old design...

Comment: Is there anything to suggest reverting to the old Twitter UI design would make a difference?

Comment: you can try reverting back and see if you regain access to your e-mail contacts. if not simply go back to the new design again

Comment: It wouldn't be regain. It was absent even before the UI change.

Comment: try a temporary change of e-mail address... put a new e-mail and then after confirmation, go back to your old e-mail. That might restart the contacts import process...